# REST entity versions

Tags: rest, restful-url

It's quite well established that we have collections and entities.

```
GET /things   -> List<Thing>
GET /things/1 -> Thing
```

But what if `thing 1` can exist in different versions. This breaks the principle that one identifier singles out a single resource.

```
GET /things/1     -> List<Thing>
GET /things/1/v1  -> Thing
```

Some properties of `thing 1` is not the same in different versions of course.

```
/things/1/v1/subthings != /things/1/v2/subthings
```

But some always are

```
/things/1/v1/id == /things/1/v2/id
/things/1/v1/name == /things/1/v2/name
```

Also, `thing 1` might have other versions than `thing 2`.

Lets say that I make `/things/1` an illegal resource identifier. Is it OK then to get all `subthings` across versions?

```
GET /things/1/subthings
```

Any 'standard' or ideas how to go about when having several versions of an entity?

Comment: Clients in a REST architecture shouldn't care about the structure of the URI, hence any answers most likely just reflect opinions. Further, according to your tag, there is no such thing as a `restful-url` as a URI/URL remains a URI/URL no matter what, regardless whether it is used in a REST architecture or in an RPC-esque manner. I therefore voted to close this question. Note further that REST isn't a 1:1 mapping of your DB entities. According to versioning URIs Fieldings take on it is [don't](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning/)

Comment: Maybe I should have had more context in the question. It is not about versioning URI's, rather how to address the same resource in the different flavours it exists in. The particular flavour happened to be version. This front facing resource schema is consists of data from multiple sources. It is important to be able to address it under the different versions as created child items inherit different properties depending on the version of the parent.

Comment: I disagree with close. This is a sincere question and answers, opinions or 'facts', will likely help many others having the same API design struggles.

Comment: `It is not about versioning URI's, rather how to address the same resource in the different flavours it exists in. The particular flavour happend to be version`. Ask yourself why a client needs this separation in first place. In a real REST architecture a client just uses the information provided by the server in a representation format understood by the client (look at HTML). A client expecting to receive a certain field not covered by the media type most likely acts upon [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) which is not in line with REST